# CertCreateCertificateContext returns ASN1 bad tag value met

Tags: c++, windows, certificate

I'm loading a .p7b certificate file into memory and then calling CertCreateCertificateContext on it, but it fails with the error "ASN1 bad tag value met.".

The call look like this:

m_hContext = CertCreateCertificateContext(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, pbCertEncoded, dwCertEncodedLen);

This returns NULL and GetLastError() returns the error mentioned above.

I created the certificate file by dragging a certificate out of the settings in IE, which then does an automatic export to a file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Update: If I export as DER Encoded Binary X.509 (cer file) the functions succeeds.  But instead I get an error when calling AcquireCredentialsHandle with the return value of CertCreateCertificateContext.

The error is: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

Comment: Please note that everything works when the certificate is installed and I open it via the system certificate store, using CertFindCertificateInStore.

What I want is, that instead of installing the certificate on all machines that needs it, I will put it in a global database and.  I will then load the BLOB from there and use CertCreateCertificateContext.  At least that is the plan.

Comment: The .cer file (PKCS#7) does not (and cannot) contain the private key and that's why most probably AcquireCredentialsHandle fails. Your best bet would be to use .pfx file (PKCS#12) with no password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open your certificate by some asn.1 editor.

Probably your certificate has been exported incorrectly or size of the certificate you pass to the api is wrong... Rather the second one option (incorrect cert construction or passing).

I found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376033(VS.85).aspx) the info that the encoding you try to use is not fully supported (see possible error values).

Comment: @user72185 If this didn't solve your problem, why is it marked as an answer and what did solve your problem?

Comment: @JohnLeidegren I suspect that using a DER-format certificate solved his/her problem, there's [a his/her own comment that says that with DER all worked out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708317/certcreatecertificatecontext-returns-asn1-bad-tag-value-met/1708759#comment1585004_1708317)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `CertOpenStore()` instead:

```
HCERTSTORE hCertStore = CertOpenStore(
    CERT_STORE_PROV_FILENAME,
    X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
    NULL,
    CERT_STORE_OPEN_EXISTING_FLAG | CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG,
    pszFilePath));
```

`CertCreateCertificateContext()` supports one certificate only, whereas PKCS #7 file can contain many.

Quote from MSDN:

> CERT_STORE_PROV_FILENAME
>   Initializes the store with certificates, CRLs, and CTLs from a file. The provider opens the file and first attempts to read the file as a serialized store, then as a PKCS #7 signed message, and finally as a single encoded certificate.

After the certificate store is open, you can use `CertEnumCertificatesInStore()` to retrieve certificate context of individual certificates from store.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see why/how CertOpenStore would substitute CertCreateCertificateContext: the latter needs to operate on a store handle (obtained previously with CertOpenStore) to add a certificate in that store. They have to be used together to accomplish the task. It looks to me that this answer doesn't fit at all the question.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I have edited my answer with further instructions how to get to particular certificate.
The OP wasn't clear what she/he is trying to accomplish anyway, was it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the certificate is in binary format.

I had similar issue when the certificate was in "Base-64 encoded X.509".
It was fixed when i used the same certificate in "DER encoded binary X.509"

You can do this easily on windows by manually importing into cert store and then exporting using the desired format.

Certificate can then be used to be installed on other machines using winapi functions.