# "ASN1 tag bad value" error importing public key from X.509 certificate

Tags: delphi, encryption, capicom

I need to encrypt something with RSA using a public key provided by a X.509 certificate. The certificate is in order (checking in Windows Explorer shows the public key, RSA 20148 bits.)

My attempt at doing the first basic step, importing the public key, fails - I get an EOSError exception "ASN1 tag bad value" on the source line tagged (being thrown by Win32Check). How do I solve this?

I am using:

- WinCrypt by Rudy Velthuis (Last modified 07 Mar 2008 )
- Delphi (XE2)

Source code:

```
try
CertPath := 'c:\somefolder\data';
pubCert := TFileStream.Create(CertPath + '\zpr_prod_public_cert.cer', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
try
  SetLength(Buffer, pubCert.Size);
  BufLen := pubCert.read(Pointer(Buffer)^, pubCert.Size);
finally
  pubCert.Free;
end;
except
  RaiseLastOSError;
  Exit;
end;
if Length(Buffer) > 1 then
begin
try
  DataLen := 0;
  // !!! the following line should actually do the trick, but it doesn't...
  // Certcontext remains empty and the errormessage is "ASN1 tag bad value met"
  CertContext := CertCreateCertificateContext(X509_ASN_ENCODING or PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, @Buffer[0], BufLen);
  if CertContext = nil then // Then I'll try another way which results in the same error :(
     Win32Check(CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING or PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, X509_PUBLIC_KEY_INFO, @Buffer[0], BufLen, CRYPT_ENCODE_ALLOC_FLAG, nil, @PublicKeyInfo, DataLen))
  else
  begin // this is actually never reached...so may be ignored
    hCProv := __CryptAcquireContext(PROV_RSA_FULL);
    if Win32Check(CryptImportPublicKeyInfo(hCProv, X509_ASN_ENCODING or PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, @certcontext.pCertInfo.SubjectPublicKeyInfo, hKey)) then
    begin
      DataLen := Length(einKey);
      BufLen := DataLen;
      Win32Check(CryptEncrypt(hkey, 0, True, 0, @EinKey[0], DataLen, BufLen));
      SetLength(einKey, DataLen);
    end;
  end;
finally
  Win32Check(CryptReleaseContext(hCProv, 0));
end;
end;
```

1. Am I reading the certificate file correctly? Should I use something else?
2. Am I using the API-Methods right?
3. What is the cause of this error ("ASN1 tag bad value")?

Comment: So... what exactly is the problem? Why "help"? Does the code not work? If not, what do you expect and what do you get? Does it crash? Does it give an empty key? Does one of the Win32Check functions fail? Etc. So far, all we see is a story of success in Windows (great!) and some code. Ie, this isn't a question as it's currently phrased, and there's no indication what if anything is wrong. You should ask a question :)

Comment: You've not explained what the problem is you're having, and "Help?" is not a meaningful or answerable question. What **specific** problem are you having with the code, and what is the **specific** question you're asking us to answer?

Comment: Incidentally, I'm told that his real name is [Rudy Velthuis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/95954/rudy-velthuis) :)

Comment: I'm sorry, that I did not make it clear where the problem is. Please read the comments in that code snippet, they state the problem, I get the "ASN1 tag bad value met" error.

Comment: I have edited your question to (a) Give it a better title (no need for tags like 'Delphi' to be in the name, also it should describe the actual problem); (b) rewrote the introduction to fit SO style better (no need for a long story); (c) make clear what is known and unknown - right now we don't know the library version, the Delphi version, etc; we also don't know how you get the error - is it an error code caught by Win32Check, an exception, etc? We don't know. You do, but you haven't told us. *Please always write a clear question with all pertinent information.*

Comment: Also, does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708317/certcreatecertificatecontext-returns-asn1-bad-tag-value-met) help?

Comment: @DavidM: Thanks a lot! I added the missing infos. And that question did not help so far. I have been there before I asked mine, but could not get any further.