# How to point to/access a cert file `CertCreateCertificateContext` function? (wincrypt api)

Tags: c++, windows, certificate-store, wincrypt, p7b

A little new to windows programming/C++. I'm trying to install a .p7b root certificate file to the Trusted Root Certificate Store. I want to use the Windows Wincrypt library. Specifically, these are the suggested steps that I got from an old forum:

1. Call `CertCreateCertificateContext` using your certificate content bytes
   in order to obtain a `PCCERT_CONTEXT`
2. Call `CertOpenSystemStore` with `szSubsystemProtocol` set to "ROOT" in
   order to obtain a `HCERTSTORE`
3. Call `CertAddCertificateContextToStore` using the above `HCERTSTORE` and
   `PCCERT_CONTEXT`.

[Here's] the api documentation for [CertCreateCertificateContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certcreatecertificatecontext). Not sure how to just point `pbCertEncoded` to my actual cert file. Should I just point it to the path? Do I have to load the cert in? What should the type be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Simon Rozman's answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708317/certcreatecertificatecontext-returns-asn1-bad-tag-value-met/29094608): We have to use `CertOpenStore()` instead of
`CertCreateCertificateContext()`, which supports one certificate only, whereas PKCS #7 file can contain many.

After the certificate store is open, you can use `CertEnumCertificatesInStore()` to retrieve certificate context of individual certificates from store.

So from my original steps to successfully install a p7b into the root store:

1. Call `CertOpenStore()` for the root store and for the actual certificate itself. This will give you two `HCERTSTORE` handles.
2. Have a while loop that will add the certificate contexts to the opened root store (using `CertAddCertificateContextToStore()`) as long as the certificate context exists (check using `CertEnumCertificatesInStore()` on the opened certificate store).